# Different behaviors of the "replace" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am working with Javascript in a Cordova application.

When running the code in the Chrome console the result is "ctsá" but when running the Cordova application in Chrome, the result is "ctst"

```
var frase = "cósá";
frase = frase.replace(/ó/gi,'t');
```

I always try to get "ctsá" and do not understand why the result is different.

Comment: Please search decodeURIComponent(yourstring) and encodeURIComponent(yourstring)

Comment: It looks like the encoding of the script file is being changed rather than a problem with `replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine in both cases, although the exact reason is not

```
var frase = "cósá";
frase = frase.replace(/\xF3/gi,'t');
```